# Getting conflict with DD-MON-RR format

Tags: oracle, hibernate, oracle-sqldeveloper

Getting conflict with DD-MON-RR format when trying with simple date format.

```
Caused By: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:884)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1167)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1289)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3593)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3637)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1495)
at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:135)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2213)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
at org.hibernate.hql.classic.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:912)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:172)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1121)
at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:79)
at com.massivos.dao.FiledataDaoImpl.getSpikeChartDetails(FiledataDaoImpl.java:112)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy105.getSpikeChartDetails(Unknown Source)
at com.massivos.service.FiledataServiceImpl.getSpikeChartDetails(FiledataServiceImpl.java:206)
at com.massivos.controller.FiledataController.getSpikeChartDetails(FiledataController.java:321)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:184)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3750)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3714)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2283)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2182)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1491)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:252)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

Here is my code

```
    public List<HistoryFileData> getSpikeChartDetails(String s_date,String s_time,String s_filter) {
    logger.info(this.getClass().getName()+"and method name is getSpikeChartDetails start");

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");              
        java.sql.Date sqldate=null;         
        try {
            Date date1 = formatter.parse(s_date);               
            sqldate=new java.sql.Date(date1.getTime());

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            logger.error(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<HistoryFileData> data=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("From HistoryFileData where  date=:d").setParameter("d", sqldate).list();
        logger.info(this.getClass().getName()+"and method name is getSpikeChartDetails end");
        return data;
}
```

Getting exception at

```
List<HistoryFileData> data=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("From HistoryFileData where  date=:d").setParameter("d", sqldate).list();
```

I donot want to change the format of sql developer other than DD_MON-RR.Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Do you have a column named `date` in the `HistoryFileData` table? If I remember correctly, `date` is a reserved word in Oracle.

Comment: Can you please see what's the format of `date` in your db ? is it yyyy-MM-dd or yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss ? If second, simply add format your date like that and see...Also check if `date` column is there in the table, you are referring to